# Equal function is not working in my java code

Tags: java, android, eclipse, equals, equals-operator

I have 2 textviews, 1 editbox and 1 button in my xml.

In my code, this line is not working:

```
if(c.equals(str)){
                Toast.makeText(GameActivity.this, "Alright",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

But next line (else statement) is working and In both cases (if & else statement) it shows else function toast ("Wrong").

Here is my code:

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game);

    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            Random r = new Random();
            int i = r.nextInt(10 - 2) + 2;
            tv.setText(i +"");
            Random r1 = new Random();
            int j = r1.nextInt((9 - 2) + 1) + 2;
            tv2.setText(j +"");
            
            int a = Integer.parseInt(tv.getText().toString());
            int b = Integer.parseInt(tv2.getText().toString());
            int result =  a*b;
            String str = String.valueOf(result);
            
            EditText txt4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            String c = txt4.getText().toString();
            
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(txt4.getText().toString())) {
                txt4.setError("Please enter your answer");
                return;
            }
            
            if(c.equals(str)){
                Toast.makeText(GameActivity.this, "Alright",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                
            }
            
            else{
                Toast.makeText(GameActivity.this, "wrong",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            
            txt4.setText("");
        }

    });
    }
```

Comment: So `c.equals(str)` returns false when you expect true? Did you debug and check the values for `c` and `str` should actually be equal? In case the condition is actually met, did you check `Toast.makeText(...)` does the right thing and doesn't have some hard coded values in it?

Comment: Run `Log.e('testing equal',c+":"+str)` before the `if` and post the results of the log, here. It should show something like `String1:StringYouThinkIsString1`

Comment: `str` seems to actually contain a number, did you try parsing the user input to a number (check if a number was entered first, e.g. with a simple regex) and compare numbers instead of strings?

Comment: Another thing: `r1.nextInt((9 - 2) + 1)` looks odd, why not simply `r1.nextInt(10 - 3)` or just `r1.nextInt(7)`?

Comment: @Thomas both of them are string

Comment: No, they aren't originally: `String str = String.valueOf(result);` - `result` is of type `int` as per your code.

Comment: Integer.parseInt(tv.getText().toString().trim()) try this for both and see what happen

Comment: @Thomas how can I convert result to string?
what do you think if i convert result to string equal function is working?

Comment: @JuanCortés Not result. Not change

Comment: your result always different each n every time

Comment: @DixitPanchal What do you mean about both?? (c & str or a & b or tv & tv2)

Comment: print both `c, str` just before the comparison and check if they are same.....

Comment: see my answer i got perfect result as you want .

Comment: @MonaK when you press the button as per your code your random value changed ,thas while you cannot get c.equal(str) true .

Comment: @DixitPanchal so how can I use both random function and c.equal(str) at the same time? what is your suggestion?

Comment: @piyushj Thank you for your help. they are not same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,
I got result

```
public class Test extends AppCompatActivity {
Button b1;
TextView t1,t2;
EditText e1;
int a,b;
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
     b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
     t1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
     t2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
     e1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    Random r = new Random();
    int i = r.nextInt(10 - 2) + 2;
    t1.setText(i +"");
    Random r1 = new Random();
    int j = r1.nextInt((9 - 2) + 1) + 2;
    t2.setText(j +"");

     a = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText().toString());
     b = Integer.parseInt(t2.getText().toString());

  b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int result =  a*b;
            String str = String.valueOf(result);

            String c = e1.getText().toString();

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(c)) {
                e1.setError("Please enter your answer");
                return;
            }

            if(c.equals(str)){
                Toast.makeText(Test.this, "Alright",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            else{
                Toast.makeText(Test.this, "wrong",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            e1.setText("");
        }

    });
}}
```

Comment: First, I'd appreciate not just dumping code at the OP but explaining what you changed and why. After all he's here to learn a thing or two. Second there's still a flaw: after entering a correct answer you'll probably want to update `a` and `b` (btw there's no need to do the calculation on each click).

Comment: If that comment is refering to your answer you should add it there, otherwise it might be hard to make the connection, especially if one later sees that thread and doesn't read all the comments.

Comment: @DixitPanchal thank you Dixit. your code is working very well. but I want to use the random number. what is your suggestion?

Comment: @MonaK when you come on this activty it will show random number

Comment: @DixitPanchal it's true. but I want when I press the button then numbers change randomly. can you help me for this?

Comment: @MonakYou can do it by taking new button and on its onlcicklistner write code to generate random number n set it on textview

Comment: @MonaK You wel come

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
String str = String.valueOf(result);
```

you should use

```
String str = Integer.toString(result);
```

Comment: That's no difference, as `String.valueOf(int)` is implemented as `return Integer.toString(i);`.